# Accessing array inside of another array to use v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an `array - 'items'` of `objects` and each of them contains an `array` of more `objects`.
I would like to `access` the second array `'productPrices'` to use `v-for`. But `items.productPrices` doesn't work for me. Should I create double loop somehow?

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(element, index) in items.productPrices">
        <td>{{ element.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <span>{{ element.amount }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ element.price }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      { 
        name: 'menu', 
        path: 'menu', 
        productPrices: [
          { amount: 100, price: 80.61, name: 'first' },
          { amount: 250, price: 72.10 },
          { amount: 500, price: 79.62 },
          { amount: 1000, price: 100.20 },
          { amount: 2500, price: 147.60 },
          { amount: 5000, price: 232.56 }
        ], 
        quantity: 0 
      },
      { 
        name: 'Etui', 
        path: 'etui', 
        productPrices: [
          { amount: 100, price: 80.61, name: 'first' },
          { amount: 250, price: 72.10 },
          { amount: 500, price: 79.62 },
          { amount: 1000, price: 100.20 },
          { amount: 2500, price: 147.60 },
          { amount: 5000, price: 232.56 }
        ],
        quantity: 0 
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khz30amb/).

Comment: `items` is an array you cannot access directly `items.productPrices`. you have to provide index like `items[0].productPrices` or you have to go through loop.

Comment: I guess, indeed, you will need to use two v-for loops. You could also first transform your data and then use one v-for, though I would  not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### While you can do this with `<template> ... </template>`

as the other two people have answered, if you wish to not nest another loop you can flatten all of the data into one array to be used, it won't be as pretty unless you move it to a function or the like.

Here's how:

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <!-- <tr v-for="(element, index) in items.map(item => item.productPrices).reduce((joinedArrays, currentArray) => joinedArrays.concat(currentArray), [])"> -->
      <tr v-for='(element, index) in currentItem().productPrices'>
        <td>{{ element.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <span>{{ element.amount }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ element.price }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your answer is the most satisfying for me but I don't want to display all `items`. I've got a computed property `currentItem` and it allows me to find the current item. I would like to display `productPrices` for the current item.

Comment: Oh if you just want the current item all you need is `(element, index) in items[currentItem].productPrices`

Comment: `currentItem() { return this.items.find(item => item.path === this.$route.params.id) }` This is computed.

Comment: Okay, so how about `(element, index) in currentItem().productPrices`

Comment: When adding this question I already had this loop, but the only thing that was wrong was instead of `items.productPrices`,  there should be `currentItem.productPrices` without `()`.

Answer (score 0):

just wrap it inside a `<template v-for="item in items">`

```
<div id="app">
      <table>
        <tbody>
        <template v-for="item in items">
          <tr v-for="(element, index) in item.productPrices">
            <td>{{ element.name }}</td>
            <td>
              <span>{{ element.amount }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ element.price }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

update on your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khz30amb/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following way:-

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid px-4 py-0>
        <h4>Test</h4>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <template v-for="(element, index) in items">
                    <tr v-for="newElement in element.productPrices" :key="index">
                        <td>{{ newElement.name }}</td>
                        <td>
                        <span>{{ newElement.amount }}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        {{ newElement.price }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

since in javascript you cant directly access the properties of array of objects for example if you have a case as above :-
where you have a array of objects that is list and you need to access the property product prices you can't just access it like list.productPrices you will first need to iterate over the higher order objects and then only you will have access to the property..

so what you will need to do is first use v-for over the list and then you can access the property productPrices and then you can iterate over it using v-for..

Hope this answers your question and doubts.